# Can an Excel Function work with sorted data as the sources? Syntax?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare a specific value between 2 sheets and then, if the values match, I want to display another value from one of these sheets. Here's what I'm trying to do:

[image: Tickets]

This "Tickets" sheet has a table of support tickets and their current status with our dev team.

.....
[image: Source]

This "Source" sheet has a table of linked-data from our source ticketing system.

.....

I want the **Tickets** sheet to display the current ticket Status (from the **Source** sheet) in the Tickets sheet's *SF Status* column for each record when that record's/row's Case No on the Tickets sheet = the Case Number on the Source sheet.

In my mind what I want to do would be expressed using the IF function but currently that's not working since every *SF Status* cell is populating with the value for FALSE.

**=IF(source!A:A=Tickets!G:G,source!B:B,"n/a")**

Any ideas will be appreciated as I'm certainly not a pro with writing Excel functions or queries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the `VLookup()` worksheet function for this:

```
=VLOOKUP(Tickets!G2;source!$A$2:$B$7;2)
```

For your information: the meaning of the last `2` is: as an input source the table `$A$2:$B$7` is taken, and we need the second column of this (the `source!B:B` from your question).

Comment: Thank you! I tested with this VLOOKUP a bit and finally got it to work as needed (and now it makes sense to me).

**=VLOOKUP(G:G,Case,2, FALSE)**

Thanks again!